# android services and activity lifecycle?

Tags: android, android-service, android-lifecycle

I am having problem with my android IntentService. When I first open the application, the service gets started by intent from the profile activity and data is fetched from this service. If I switch to other activity and then back service is still running and that is ok.

However if you press back, so that activity is finished and put in the background, the service is still working as the application is in background but If I get it back to foreground service stops. I do not know why. Bellow is my code, please help.

I have read activity life cycle couple of times and still do not get it why this is happening.

What is weird is that Service receive data one more time before it stops when MainActivity is brought back to running state. Service is not crashing.

**Service**

```
public class SomeService extends IntentService
{
    public static final String extra = "someData";

    public SomeService()
    {
        super(SomeService.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        Log.e("SomeService", "starting service");

        while (true)
        {
            SomeData data = Api.getNewSocketData();

            //Broadcast data when received to update the view
            Intent broadcastData = new Intent();
            broadcastData.setAction(dataBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_DATA_RECEIVED);
            broadcastData.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
            broadcastData.putExtra(extra, " ");
            sendBroadcast(broadcastData);

            Log.e("SomeService", "received from socket");
        }

    }


}
```

**Receiver**

```
public class dataBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_RECEIVED = "net.bitstamp.intent.action.ACTION_SOMEDATA_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Log.e("receiver", "data received");
    }
}
```

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(dataBroadcastReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(dataBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_DATA_RECEIVED);
    intentFilter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    dataBroadcastReceiver = new dataBroadcastReceiver();
    registerReceiver(dataBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

    Intent someService = new Intent(this, SomeService.class);
    startService(someService);

}
```

I really need help on this. Thanks

Comment: Check logcat, is the service crashing?

Comment: no it isn't... the event onHandleEvent is not executed...

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but you should check if the service is already running before calling startService() in onResume(). You're queueing up more requests that can't execute. How is the onHandleIntent() call ever completing?

Comment: Check when onDestroy() is being called on the service, this might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to the up the `IntentService` in an infinite loop. It will block all other incoming requests. From the documentation:

All requests are handled on a single worker thread -- they may take as long as necessary (and will not block the application's main loop), but only one request will be processed at a time.

Your Service is likely still happily running along, it just isn't processing your new request because your old one is still being handled in the infinite loop.

Comment: how should I do this then? when I get data from socket end the service and run it again?

Comment: It really depends on what the service is intended to do. If you want the service to maintain a connection to your web service and broadcast new data, use your own thread(s) rather than the one used by `IntentService`.